# Testable code - am I doing it right?

Tags: unit-testing

So, I'm trying to get my head around how to write testable code, and am playing with a project for a .srt (subtitles) player.

I have a class Player, which has the properties frames, and sourcePath.

I have a method loadFrames() which I would normally write to just open the file found at sourcePath, parse it, and populate the frames accordingly.

However - I want to be able to test this. I want to avoid having to make calls to the file system - I want to be able to define what the contents of the 'file' at sourcePath are in my test.

The way I have gone about this is to make the method loadFrames take a parameter of type IFileLoader which has a method String[] GetSourceText(String source);

The real FileLoader used in production will parse the file found at source. In my tests I use a FakeFileLoader which returns values I set to it's contents property.

So - my question is - am I doing this in a good way. It doesn't feel like the way I would normally write code. Writing testable code certainly seems to feel different to what I am used to, and whilst this has satisfied my current requirement to be able to specify the contents of the source - I want to know if the way I have done it is logical. Is there a better, more sensible way of achieving the same result?

All help and insights are much appreciated!

P.S I'm not using any mocking frameworks etc, just plain code. I'm actually coding in C# which I never do (normally Java) but I certainly view this to be a general testing question, and not specific to any one language.

Answer (score 0):

So far, so good. There's no need to choose a mocking framework if your tests are kept concise and useful.

Besides that, "right" test-driven programming, IMO, is working in such a way that you start with valuable expectations and end with actual, fully testable code. Or simply, working from outside in. Conversely, "wrong" is starting with unclear expectations and ending with much unnecessary, brittle, and buggy code.

Answer (score 0):

If the method `loadFrames()` didn't originally have a parameter, then it probably would be best to avoid adding one. Instead create a factory method that returns an object of type `IFileLoader` and use that factory method instead of the parameter.

Then for testing create a subclass of `Player`, say `TestPlayer`, that returns the testing `IFileLoader`.

I would also recommend using mocking frameworks.

It sounds like you are adding tests to legacy code. If so, I suggest the book 'Working Effectively with Legacy Code' which discusses adding tests to existing code.

Comment: I'm not working with legacy code - this is a personal project - very small, a large part of what I hope to gain is to improve my understanding of testable code. So far very little code wriiten.